# How correctly include module of another project in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I want to include module a1 in project B.

a1 depends on and includes a2

```
Projects
  A
    a1
      build.gradle
    a2
      build.gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle

  B
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

In settings.gradle of B project I added:

```
rootProject.name = 'B'
rootProject.setProjectDir(new File(".")

include ':a1'
project(':a1').setProjectDir(new File(settingsDir.getParentFile(), "/A/a1"))
```

In build.gradle of B:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':a1')
}
```

So, when gradle build project B error appears that a2 can't be found.

Then I included a2 in settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'B'
    rootProject.setProjectDir(new File(".")

    include ':a1',
            ':a2'

    project(':a1').setProjectDir(new File(settingsDir.getParentFile(), "/A/a1"))
    project(':a2').setProjectDir(new File(settingsDir.getParentFile(), "/A/a2"))
```

This solution works for me, but I am not sure if it is correct way to add module from other project.

Is there a better solution?